# iOS programatically setting up device in AP mode

Tags: ios, network-programming, wifi

During the application lifecycle, how can device be put into Access Point mode?

Like turning on the Personal Hotspot.

And is it possible to assign SSID to that network during runtime?

Comment: All of this is not possible with the official SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do the above with public API.

If you want to use private api there is a file located in the Preferences folder, along with the `com.apple.SpringBoard.plist`:

`/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.MobileInternetSharing.plist`
In that file, you will want to set `1023` for key State to enable the Tethering feature. To disable the feature, you will want to set `1022` for key State.

This action is only possible on a jailbroken device

Comment: I wont be trying jailbroken path, but unfortunately that is true. The only thing that can be done legally concerning network settings is to obtain info about current network.